# Exporting app interface as XAML: is XAML compiled?

Tags: wpf, xaml, compilation, windows-phone-8, xamlreader

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app and would like to not only be able to load new XAML into my app using XamlReader.Load, but to also read my app's current XAML and be able to parse and/or output it.

How much of a Windows Phone app's XAML is BAML and how much is loose? Is it possible to get the current app's XAML?

Comment: You may also include your .XAML files in the package, together with the binaries, then you can load them from disk at runtime.

Comment: That's a good idea-- once the external .XAML files were loaded, would the originals be edited as they change in the app's runtime, or would they be loaded as new copies and left unchanged, requiring me to update them every time I wanted a XAML change saved?